# Copy GIF from notes on macOS

Tags: macos, high-sierra, notes.app

It's possible to copy and paste animated GIF to macOS notes app. And it stores them as animated GIFs as they can be previewed with the animation. However, when you copy one from notes it just copies the image in different format which is not animated. How can I copy animated GIF from macOS notes and paste it to another app?

**Update:**
When I try to paste it into Mail app and then send it, it just sends as plain image (not animated one). If I google the gif in a browser and press Copy Image and then paste it into the Mail app everything works fine.

Comment: I just tested, on macOS High Sierra, copying an animated GIF file in Finder and pasting it to a new note in the Notes app. I then selected the pasted file and right-click Copy, and then pasted it into several different documents in different apps. In all cases the pasted object was the animated GIF, not just a single image. So, I **can not** reproduce your issue.

Comment: @user3439894: If you open an animated gif in Preview, you'll see only a single static image. The other images can be seen in the Sidebar.

Comment: @Seamus, That is normal and expected in Preview. I also didn't paste it into Preview as it's more of a viewer and not the type of app I necessarily be choosing to paste something in; however, after copying from Notes and then in Preview selecting File > New From Clipboard and saving it as a .gif, it maintains its animation in e.g. Finder.

Comment: @user3439894: I understand... the cmt was offered only as possible explanation of OP's question.

Comment: @Seamus, Sorry, but I do not see it as a "possible explanation of OP's question" because the Paste command on the Edit menu in Preview is normally grayed out and not active. As an example, if in Preview I have a PDF document open and then copy the .gif from Notes and then try to paste it in Preview, it cannot be pasted. So IMO Preview is not the focus of the OP's question and until he adds explicit and specific information the question is ambiguous. Additionally, opening  the GIF file in Preview is not the focus of the question, copy and pasting from Notes is and it works for me as I stated.

Comment: @user3439894 Please see updated question. It's inserted into Mail app as a plain image for some reason. However, when I just copy it from browser, it's being inserted fine.